# Powershell and backing up event logs

Tags: events, powershell, backup, extract

I am trying to find out how i can backup or extract the last 24 hours of my application logs on several windows 2008r2 servers all in the same domain. If possible i want to keep them in .evtx file format. Then save all files back onto either one server or a domain pc.

Comment: You can redirect all Windows Event Logs to one server using Eventlog Forwarding, it's built into Windows. See: http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2008/08/11/quick-and-dirty-large-scale-eventing-for-windows.aspx Have you considered that instead?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: This for an admin process. I do not want the complete log, just the past 24 hours. I want to be able to run a scheduled script every 24 hours to extract the previous 24 hours of logs. I would like to do this from one place and save all collected data in the same place.

Comment: You can create views to display events of a particular time frame, e.g. the past 24 hours. There's no need to duplicate event logs for that.

Comment: You seem to be missing my point here, At present i login to several servers, filter my application logs to show the last 24 hours of events, save that file and repeat. Then because i am in a secure environment i have to copy all the logs off the system and publish on a secure support intranet site, for dev and support people to digest. So based on my requirements can you help me automate this process.

Comment: Forwarding events to a central loghost has already been suggested.